# How can I create yii2 migration with comment for table?

Tags: yii2, console-application, database-migration

Is there any native way or extantion for that?
Or to create separate migration for adding comment to table?

Comment: I need to add comment to table exactly by console command.

Comment: I need something like:
yii migrate/create create_test_table --fields="..." --comment="Comment for my table"

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for this.

```
$this->addCommentOnTable('table', 'Comment here...');
```

Add this method inside the migration file.

Comment: I know this method, it's easy. But I need to add comment to table exactly from console.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible to do from console command directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since Yii 2.0.14:

```
php yii migrate/create create_my_table_table --comment='My comment for table'
```

or

```
php yii migrate/create create_my_table_table -C='My comment for table'
```

Result

```
    public function safeUp(): bool
    {
        $this->createTable('{{%my_table}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        ]);
        $this->addCommentOnTable('{{%my_table}}', 'My comment for table');
    }
```